# CREATE DATABASE... hangs and new base folder is not being created on filesystem

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

We upgraded from postgres 9.1 to postgres 10 recently on a CentOS 7 server.  We installed from scratch and restored the databases onto the new installation.

The databases restored fine, and everything appears to be working normally, however, when we try to create new databases, most of the time it hangs until we cancel it.

I ran an strace on the process, and it appears that the new folder isn't being created on the filesystem, and goes through an infinite timeout error.

Simple database create command:

```
CREATE DATABASE ubm_vanguard_academy;
```

and the strace:

```
epoll_wait(3, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=21012256, u64=21012256}}], 1, -1) = 1
recvfrom(11, "Q\0\0\0*CREATE DATABASE ubm_vanguar"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 43
lseek(30, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 8192
lstat("base/1012469", 0x7ffd04544370)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
kill(93844, SIGINT)                     = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

The permissions on the folders are all correct, and once in a great while, it works normally and we're able to create a new database.

If we restart the postgres server, it seems we're able to create databases normally, but after a period of time the problem comes back.

I'm kind of at a loss here.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the filesystem being too busy to create the folder in time, or if there is something going on with the WAL that would prevent the folder from being created.  The database server is quite busy at times serving multiple databases, and we never have a problem with timeouts or extensive wait states, it's just creating databases that give us issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might adding [IF NOT EXISTS] to "CREATE DATABASE ubm_vanguard_academy;" help in this case? as in:
CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] ubm_vanguard_academy;

Comment: I don't believe that's an option in the CREATE DATABASE command.  But I've verified that the database doesn't exist in the pg_database table.  And as I was typing this, I tested it again, and it created.  So it's very random.

Comment: out of curiosity what is the exact version? not just major. did you look in groups if other people met similar problem? to looks some sort of bug

Comment: Version is 10.1.  I've looked in groups and didn't see anything similar.  I saw some issues where it was taking extremely long because it was writing the files, but that was a filesystem issue.  I haven't seen anything where it fails to create the directory all together.